# Differences between ActionExecutingContext and HttpActionContext

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4

When I add a filter attribute to an api controller it doesn't work because of using `ActionExecutingContext`. When I find the solution which is I have to use `HttpActionContext` it works fine. So what is the major differences between them ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in one of my earlier MVC solutions, my custom filter used `ActionExecutingContext`. In that solution, the packages.config says:

```
package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0"
```

In a newer MVC solution, when I create a similar custom attribute / filter, the override for OnActionExecuting wants me to now pass in a `HttpActionContext`.. and that NuGet is:

```
package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3"
```

I'm still researching what the difference is, too. But, I can definitely see they changed this up between versions of AspNet.Mvc